# subtracting time in Java

Tags: java, date, time

Hello I am trying to create a teacher utility to port over to android OS.  However I am running into a little trouble.  I would like to create a class called Period.  This class would contain the start and end time of that period.  ie.  Period one starts at 7:45 and ends at 8:45.  I would also like to have a method for time left in period.   for example it is now 8:10 and there are 35 minutes left.  I am able to get the current time from System.currentTimeMillis().  However I am having trouble trying to figure out the best way to store the start and end time of the periods.  i have taken a look at the Calendar class in Java and it seems like time is always tied to a date as well as a time.  This does not seem to make seance for my application since the end time of the period happens on multiple days and not just on one particular date.  Any help understanding this would be a great help.  Thanks all

Comment: why would posting code help here - the user seems to have articulated the problem sensibly in their question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to be able to compare the start and end time of the period with the current time, then you need a way to compute the date and time of the period's bounds for today.

So get a Calendar instance for today, set its time to 7:45, and compare the time of the calendar with the current time (same for the upper bound, of course).

To represent each bound, you could simply use an int for the hours and a second int for the minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/index.html) library.  The DateTime object has what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

Specifically, Period: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_period.html

Answer (score 0):

Calendar is a king of wrapper around the class Date which has mostly deprecated functions. I've heard that the JodoTime API is great for comparing two timestamps (http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

One way to store the start and end time for the periods would be to instantiate an ArrayList of dates so you can compare any given time to the lesson periods.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you should store the time as a number of seconds (optionally milliseconds) from last midnight. Thus, your period one, 7.45, starts at 45*60 (45 minutes * 60 seconds per minute) + 7*60*60 (7 hours times minutes times seconds!) = 2 700 + 25 200 = **27 900**.

Do the same calculation for your end date, and as long as they begin and end on the same day,  you can easily subtract the difference and thus get the interval in between. If they do not happen on the same date, then Java's time and date classes are both excellent and a must. These classes essentially work the same algorithm, but do not count the seconds from "last midnight", instead they count the amount of milliseconds from the UNIX epoch time (1 January 1970).

Comment: That would lead to incorrect results twice per year, due to DST. These two days, 7:45 would be 6 hours and 45 minutes after midnight, or 8 hours and 45 minutes after midnight.

Comment: **Might** lead to problems related to the transition yes. However, the topic starter said "This does not seem to make seance for my application [..]". I think he want to be completely agnostic in this regard. Say he's building a time reporting tool, then a nominal approach makes sense due to the fact that some given combinations of  date and time can be set in multiple time zones (DST = a time zone). Say DST happened at 13.00 and we had to turn back our clock one hour. How many seconds since midnight has passed 12.30? 12.30 that day can obviously be set in two different time zones!

Comment: So at the end of the day, my approach has always been to me agnostic. If you insist on using the calendar class, make sure you kill the default TimeZone. And threat time zone transitions as close to the end user as possible. To continue my last example, the application could identify that a transition occurred and even make assumptions but has to always double check with the client that the calculation is right. You can as Java's classes already do, store all as milliseconds since Unix time, and keep a time zone identifier (say a offset from UTC or Olsson db identifier) separate.

Comment: The OP wants to compare the bounds of the period with the current time. The current time only makes sense in a given time zone. 9 o'clock is a time which, in milliseconds since the epoch, translates differently depending on the user's timezone.

Comment: "current time only makes sense in a given time zone". No. A time measurement, given a time zone, always have an offset stated with regard to UTC. Thus, it can be compared with any other time statement undependable of time zones. Either way, `System.currentTimeMillis` give the amount of milliseconds from epoch time. Thus it is already completely time zone agnostic. Perhaps one more reason to stay of the zones and count seconds since last midnight?

Comment: Go back to my first comment. DST isn't applied the same way in my timezone and in UTC. So, once per year, your algorithm will tell that 8 hours have passed since last midnight, which obviously means it's 8 o'clock, which is plain wrong, because this day, in my timezone, we went from 2 o'clock to 3 o'clock in a nanosecond, which means it's actually 9 o'clock although 8 hours have elapsed since midnight. So the worker who should leave at 8 o'clock will actually leave at 9 with your algorithm, and will leave at 8 with mine.